# How to publish a command to all users in unix

Tags: bash, unix, command

I have a command which is not working if I log-in to Unix using my ID.

```
$ db2licm -l
-bash: db2licm: command not found
```

But if the root gives the same command in the format `./db2licm -l`,  he gets valid results.

How can root publish the command so that it can be used by me also?

Answer (score 1):

The `./` at the beginning of `root`'s version of the command indicates that it is in the current directory (presumably `root`'s home directory).  To make it accessible to other users it should be moved or copied to a directory that is in their executable search path, such as `/usr/bin`, and its permission bits should be set so that anyone can execute it (normally mode 0755).

Usually that sort of thing should be done via the program's installer, not manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have a single answer, because this depends on a lot of factor.

**Access**

First of all, in order to run a program from your account, you need to have execution privilege on the executable. You can check that you indeed have execution rights using `ls -l` :

```
$ ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 934336 2014-09-27 04:01 /bin/bash
```

Here, the characters `rwxr-xr-x` are respectively for user (root), group (root) and others access (three characters/flags for each). In my case, anybody can execute `/bin/bash` because the `x` flag is set on the last three character block (rwxr-xr-**x**).

**Finding the executable**

Secondly, the system needs to be able to find the executable. In your example, you specify that `root` launches the executable by prepending `./` before the command name, which basically mean "execute this program located in the current directory". Navigate anywhere else in your filesystem's tree structure and the command won't execute anymore.

To execute a command without specifying its exact path, this command must be in a directory included in your `PATH` environment variable. You can either add your command's directory to your `PATH` variable, move that command into a directory already present in your `PATH` variable (like `/usr/bin`) or create a symbolic link into a directory already present in your `PATH` variable, pointing to your command in its current directory.

**Adding to PATH**

If you'd like to add your executable's directory to your `PATH` environment variable on a permanent basis, you only need to modify your profile (usually `~/.bashrc` if you are using `bash` or `~/.profile`) by adding the following line :

```
export PATH="/the/directory/to/add:$PATH"
```

Note the `:` between your path and the `$PATH` variable.